# Typescript Custom Node Modules

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to fully understand how Typescript works in a Node.js project. To accomplish this I have created my own `custom_modules` folder with a separate `@types` folder underneath for my declarations while the actual implementation is under the `custom_modules` attempting to mimic the structure of `node_modules`. My goal is to make this module usable in the project non-relatively with separate declaration and implementation. I have been able to setup a project that compiles with this setup, but running it errors with:

`Cannot find module 'foo'`

The source is available here:
https://github.com/anorborg/learn-ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `node_modules` folder is a somewhat special case in how typings get handeled. This is a result of how nodejs works. Take a look at the [module-resolution] doucmentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), it describes more in depth how module resolution work in typescript.

But in short to answer your question: you can not use non-relative module paths in this way. Node will look for the file in `node_modules` at runtime, and will not find it there. The `paths` property in the tsconfig.json is there to solve problems that can occur in other cases, as when targeting RequireJS or SystemJS for example, but not when targeting node.